# Por qué esta función da como resultado 24?

Tags: php

Estoy empezando en PHP y no puedo entender este resultado. Me podrían explicar? y gracias:

```
<?php
function f($i){
    if ($i == 0 || $i == 1)
        return 1;
    return $i * f($i - 1);
}
echo f(4);
?>

// 24
```

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n#:~:text=Recursi%C3%B3n%20o%20recursividad%20es%20la,partir%20de%20un%20mismo%20tipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relativamente tiene que ver con la lógica del programa

```
function f($i){
    if ($i == 0 || $i == 1)
       return 1;
    return $i * f($i - 1);
 }
 echo f(4);
```

En especifico en esta parte `return $i * f($i - 1);`

al enviar el **4** pasa lo siguiente `4*f(4-1)` **AQUÍ ESTAS MANDANDO LLAMAR NUEVAMENTE LA FUNCIÓN PERO CON VALOR 3** y te da resultado 6, por lo que en tu planteamiento original tendrías 4*(6) = 24

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.